# Rails default image absolute URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a newbie question:

I'm storing a default URL (pointing to an image that's stored on server) as the default image for a model, such as `/assets/project_default.png`. The user can also set the URL to a remote URL as well.

How do I display the URL as an absolute URL so it's `http://xxxxxx.com//assets/project_default.png` but also support a user's remote URL?

If I use `"#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}`, that'll always apply. I'd like to apply only if the URL isn't remote.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I'm reading your question right, you could do something like...

application_helper.rb

```
def absolute_image_url (url)
  if url[0] == "/"
    return "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}" + url
  else
    return url
  end
end
```

Or add it into the model, etc.

Comment: Great idea, I ended up using the uri package: require "uri"